# Can I use a method from another class in an sql query?

Tags: java, sql

I currently have this method in my `Customer.java` class, and was looking to use it in my `createCustomerAccount` class.

```
public String generateCustomerId(){
  String customerId=new String();
  int a,b,c;
  try {
      ResultSet rs=db.read(db.connect().prepareStatement("SELECT idCustomer FROM Customer"));
      db.disconnect();
      if(rs.next()==false){
          customerId="ACC000";
      }
      else{
          while(rs.next()){}
          customerId=rs.getString("idDiscount");
          a=customerId.charAt(3);
          b=customerId.charAt(4);
          c=customerId.charAt(5);
          if(c<9){
              c++;
              customerId="ACC"+a+b+c;
          }else if(b<9){
              c=0;
              b++;
              customerId="ACC"+a+b+c;
          }else{
              b=0;
              c=0;
              a++;
              customerId="ACC"+a+b+c;
          }

      }
  }   catch (SQLException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(Customer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  } 

  return customerId;
}
```

My `createCustomerAccount` class currently looks like this:

```
private void btnCreateActionPerformed(java.awt.event.ActionEvent evt) {                                                  
  AccountName = txtAccHolder.getText();
  contactName = txtContact.getText();
  phone = txtPhone.getText();
  email = txtEmail.getText();
  address = txtAddress.getText();


  String sql = ("INSERT INTO customer(idCustomer,accountName,contactName,address,PhoneNo,email) VALUES ('"+id+ "', '"+AccountName+"', '"+contactName+"','"+address+"','"+phone+"','"+email+"')");

  try {
    db.write(db.connect().prepareStatement(sql));

  } catch (SQLException ex) {
      Logger.getLogger(Customer.class.getName()).log(Level.SEVERE, null, ex);
  } finally {
      db.disconnect();
  }
}
```

Would I be able to use `generateCustomerId` method in the method of my button in the separate class?

Comment: you can call the method using object of that class like this **new Customer().generateCustomerId()**

Answer (score 0):

So, the SQL you are using selects the id's of all the customers.  Perhaps you are trying to select "AC" + (max(id) + 1).  I'm not sure that's what it's doing.

You can definitely create an instance of the Customer class and call the method in your createCustomerAccount, as follows:

```
Customer customer = new Customer();
String customerId = customer.generateCustomerId();
```

Or you could make the method static and call it as follows:

```
String customerId = Customer.generateCustomerId();
```

However, I personally think it's better to generate id's in the database, as follows:

```
CREATE TABLE account (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    name CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL
);

CREATE TABLE customer (
    id SERIAL NOT NULL,
    name CHARACTER VARYING(255) NOT NULL,
    id_account INTEGER NOT NULL REFERENCES account(id) ON DELETE RESTRICT
);

INSERT INTO customer(name, id_account) VALUES ('customer name', 7) RETURNING id;
```